# HTML Custom Component <script> tag functions "is not defined" in FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, custom-component, script-tag

Why "Custom Component"  tag function "is not defined" in FireFox.
Although it works well with Google Chrome and Edge ?

What is wrong or what I miss to get this to work ?
A simple example consists of "hello" function has been constructed and tested on Edge, Chrome and FireFox.

Edit: I tried to add code to snippet, but I had to move template to snippet's HTML section as it's not accepted in snippet's JavaScript section, although it's implemented in ".js" file in original implementation.

Adding template to HTML section made it work on FireFox but I still need to get it work on FireFox using original implementation "template" written and added by ".js" file.

```js
class AKEnode extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        const template = document.querySelector('template#template_ake_node');
        const clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
        root.appendChild(clone);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("ake-node ceated.");
    }
}

customElements.define('ake-node', AKEnode);
```

```html
<template id="template_ake_node">
    <script>
        function hello(){
            alert("Hello Ahmed !");
        };
    </script>
    <div class="ake_node">
        <span class="title">TITLE</span>
        <button class="add" onClick="hello()">Say Hello!</button>
    </div>
</template>

<ake-node id="ake_node"></ake-node>
```

```js
const ake_node_doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`
<template id="template_ake_node">
    <script>
        function hello(){
            alert("Hello Ahmed !");
        };
    </script>
    <div class="ake_node">
        <span class="title">TITLE</span>
        <button class="add" onClick="hello()">Say Hello!</button>
    </div>
</template>`, 'text/html');

const ake_node_template = ake_node_doc.head.firstChild;

document.head.appendChild(ake_node_template);

class AKEnode extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        const template = document.querySelector('template#template_ake_node');
        const clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);
        root.appendChild(clone);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("ake-node ceated.");
    }
}

customElements.define('ake-node', AKEnode);
```

Comment: Because defining an element does not happen synchronously. In order to run code that relies on your element _actually_ existing, use [whenDefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined).

Comment: Please add an executable StackOverflow Snippet to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I tried to add code to snippet, but I had to move template to snippet's HTML section as it's not accepted in snippet's JavaScript section, although it's implemented in ".js" file in original implementation.

Adding template to HTML section made it work on FireFox but I still need to get it work on FireFox using original implementation "template" written and added by ".js" file.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks a lot I'm trying to focus and understand many points,  Why it's not working while  <script> section is implemented before <div> ? Why it works fine on Edge and Chrome but not FireFox ? Why specially FireFox has asyncronization issue/different implementation ? How to edit current code to work with whenDefine ?

Answer (score 0):

You are jumping through a lot of unrequired hoops to work with a `<template>`.  If you do not want a `<template>` tag in your HTML, then replace the `append` with a `.innerHTML = '...'`

Only HTML and CSS are scoped to shadowDOM.

**The `<script>` in your template will be scoped to Global Scope: `window`**

```html
<template id="AKE-NODE">
  <script>
    function hello() {
      alert("Hello Faiza! scope:" + this);
    };
  </script>
  <button class="add" onClick="hello()">Say Hello!</button>
</template>

<script>
  customElements.define('ake-node', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      let template = (id) => document.getElementById(id).content.cloneNode(true);
      super() // sets AND returns 'this' scope
        .attachShadow({mode:'open'})  // sets AND returns this.shadowRoot
        .append(template(this.nodeName)); // super was called, can now use 'this'
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      console.log(this.localName, "created!");
      this.onclick = (evt) => console.log("clicked:",this.getAttribute("me"));
    }
  });
</script>

<ake-node me="One"></ake-node>
<ake-node me="Two"></ake-node>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I'm using it in ".js" for a different purpose/architecture model.

Comment: Which append you mean to replace with innerHTML ? Is this will make <script> scoped to shadow DOM ?

Comment: there is only one ``.append`` in the above code, replace it with ``.innerHTML = HTML`` And no, you can't scope a ``<script>`` tag to anything but global Scope